# Using Array.Sort without using both values in array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

I have an array like this:

```
var array = [{value: 1, text:"one"},{value: 2, text:"two"},{value: 3, text:"three"}]
```

and I want to sort it based on this variable: `var order = '1,3,2';`

Meaning, it will be in the order of `1,3,2` where its ordered by the `value` property of the object in the array.

I am using it in an AngularJS `ng-repeat` array, but I cannot use the custom compare on the `orderBy` because I am using version [1.2.14](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.14/docs/api/ng/filter/orderBy) and it came out in [1.5.7](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.7/docs/api/ng/filter/orderBy). I cannot change the version.

I thought of extracting the logic out from AngularJS and just sorting the array in [javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), but am getting stuck because it sorts based on values in the array and not from another value.

For example, I have tried this with a custom sort but I only want to compare one index at a time. I don't want to loop through each pair of things to sort. I only want to use `a` from the function and not both `a` and `b`.

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('test', []);

  app.controller("test", function($scope) {
    $scope.selectedOption = {};

    $scope.availableOptions = [{
      value: 1,
      text: "one"
    }, {
      value: 2,
      text: "two"
    }, {
      value: 3,
      text: "three"
    }];

    $scope.availableOptions.sort(sortOptions);
  });

  var sortOptions = function(a, b) {
    var sortBy = '1,3,2';

    var values = sortBy.split(',');
    for (val in values) {
      v = parseInt(val);
      if (v === a.value) {
        return 0;
      } else if (v < a.value) {
        return -1;
      } else if (v > a.value) {
        return 1;
      }
    }
  };

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="test">
  <select ng-model="selectedOption.value">
    <option ng-repeat="option in availableOptions" value="{{option.value}}">{{option.text}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I would like the dropdown to have `One, Three, Two` in that order from top to bottom. Is there a way to only use `.sort` with only one value in the array at a time? And only compare it once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can lookup the index of `value` in `order`. It would be easier if `order` is an `array`, but if it *must* be a string, then you can still look up the index of in strings.

```js
let array = [{value: 1, text: "one"}, {value: 2, text: "two"}, {value: 3, text: "three"}];
let order = [1, 3, 2]; // '1,2,3' will also work

let sorted = array.sort((a, b) => order.indexOf(a.value) - order.indexOf(b.value));

console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: Thanks, choosing this because I need to support an older version of IE.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a `Map` for the wanted sorting order, but you need both parameters for sorting, because you need to get the relative order.

```js
var array = [{ value: 1, text: "one" }, { value: 2, text: "two" }, { value: 3, text: "three" }],
    orderStr = '1,3,2',
    order = new Map(orderStr.split(',').map((k, v) => [+k, v]));

array.sort((a, b) => order.get(a.value) - order.get(b.value));

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add another property like SortOrder and assign it numbers from 0... N in the order you need to see them (compile your 1,3,2 to 0,1,2)
and than use that field as orderBy field without any special, custom logic?